# Java FAQ equivalent of C++ FAQ lite?

Tags: java, c++

Is there any Java FAQ equivalent of the Parashift [C++ FAQ lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/) ?

(Books like Effective Java are handy to have around, but I'm looking for a comprehensive online (advanced) Java FAQ that I could use)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing quite like it that I know of, but [Angelika Langer's Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) covers generics pretty well.

Also, you might find [Roedy Green's Java Glossary](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/jgloss.html) handy.

Comment: +1 The glossary is an excellent resource.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why Java have no USENET style FAQ that Java was started as proprietary platform and in last years come with excellent:

- [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/)

and:

- [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

While Java Language Specification is very technical and have very few examples Java Tutorial is more easy to read and it have a lot of examples.

Answer (score 0):

There is http://www.cafeaulait.org/javafaq.html but it is quite old.

Comment: Very old :  Last-modified: 1997/10/06  !